# Translate overlapping Views on scroll with different speed

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview

In google play app, you would have seen when when we do scroll up action any where on screen, upper branding area moves slowly and the content section moves faster rate. how can this be achieved?

i though of one option: will add two views full screen inside relative layout, in top view will give margin top of some value and background is transparent.
will add scroll listener and on scroll action of will animate the bottom view at slower rate.

will this be proper way or does better way exists?

Regards.

Comment: Your solution seems acceptable, even though the question itself is a bit generic. Try it out in code, and if you're still not satisfied, please add your code and ask a more specific question regarding the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [library](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) it has lots of types of `actionbar` `animations`